# How to associate 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I currently have three models, user, property, tenants. When I created a property the user_id is passed to the property via the associations:

```
class User
  has_many :properties
end

class Property
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tenants
end

class Tenant
  belongs_to :property
end
```

I run into problems with trying to pass a property_id to tenants. I have tried several combinations of associations but nothing seems to work.

My tenant db has a property_id column and I can manually add a property_id to it and everything works ok. But what I would like to be able to do is to click "new tenant" from within a property and that tenant is then associated with the property but it's not happening.

I have even tried passing the property_id into a hidden field within the tenant form via:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/new_tenant', :locals => { :tenant => Tenant.new(:property_id => @property.id) } %>
```

but this hasn't worked either.

Any suggestions would save what is left of my sanity.

Thanks,
Tony.

Comment: Do you have has_many:belongs_to association between property and tenant?

Comment: Yea in the property model I have has_many :tenants and in the tenant model I have belongs_to :property

Comment: When you say that it's not working, what's the error or behavior of the application exactly?

Comment: Are the association methods working? If you instantiate a Tenant with let's say Property.first.tenants.new, is the property_id filled?

Comment: When I say it's not working I mean that no property_id is being populated in the property_id column of the tenant table. The tenant is being created but it has no association to a property.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `belongs_to`, `has_many`, etc in the models is not enough to create a relationship in the database. What they do is tell Rails which associations to make by looking at the `*_id` fields that are already in the database.

You need to make sure you have a `property_id` of type `Integer` on your Tenant table. If you don't have one, you can add it by generating a migration:

```
rails g migration add_property_id_to_tenants property_id:integer
```

And then running `rake db:migrate` (and similar for other models if they are also missing these columns)

Comment: I already have a property_id column in the tenant table but its not being populated with a property_id.